# Centering three buttons in three divs on the same line

Tags: javascript, css, html, button

I have three buttons, inside three divs, and I need to center them on the same line.
They were created with the createElement() method. Button and Div.
This is the only way I know for creating buttons within functions or script tags or if-else statements. Or at least the only way that works for me. ^^;
I bet a visual would help at this point.

```
function threeGameButtons()
{
    buttonDiv = createElement("div");
    buttonDiv = setAttribute("center");
    //This ^ has been to center the divs, and has done so by putting them on  
    //top of each other. I believe I understand why though.
    gameButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    gameText = document.createTextNode("text");
    gameButton = appendChild(gameText);
    buttonDiv.id = "buttonID";
    gameButton.onclick = myFunction;
    //calls a function for the game
    buttonDiv.appendChild(gameButton);
    document.body.appendChild(buttonDiv);

    //two more buttons
}
```

So the three buttons made like this are called in a function earlier in the game. (I don't think I mentioned, but it's probably obvious now: this is for a game).
I'd love to just make a container div and center that or something but I'm completely unaware of how to do so when the divs are created like this in a function.
And I've tried some CSS to center the divs and buttons. Oh boy have I tried. But my efforts have been fruitless. I could give you everything, but I'd have to think back to all of the CSS methods I've tried.
One I've tried though:

```
#buttonID2 (Second and center button)
{
    margin:0 auto;
}
#buttonID (First and left button)
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
}
#buttonID3 (Third and right Button)
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:200px;
}
```

When I try this, the third button goes to the second line, but goes to the right.
And I've tried adding inline-block to margin:0 auto; and it stops the second button from centering.
The other two still go left and right of the center though.
My intention isn't really to have them go that far to the left and right, but for right now, I just don't want them overlapping the middle button.

A note; All of this happens on the page that the function calling them happens. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not. I thought I'd throw that in though, in case it does.

Comment: Why not use tables? Also, if you could provide an example inside a fiddle (or whichever site you prefer), that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm such a noob.. Fiddle? I mean, are you talking about the JSFiddle I see people use on here all the time? And can you use tables inside of functions..?

Comment: Yes, I meant a jsfiddle. I'm also not sure what you mean by "can you use tables inside of function". I assumed it was a layout issue, not javascript. If I'm mistaken, please clarify your problem a bit further.

Comment: Is it necessary to create the buttons in JS? Why such pain?

Comment: @Kippie- I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniewrathh/6mNJX/3/) for the entire function (I'll probably add it to the initial post too). I think that'll be the best way to explain or help. I'm not sure, you can decide. And, I suppose it could be considered both a JavaScript and Layout issue because the buttons that I need to position are in the JavaScript.

Comment: @akinuri- Oh my gosh, I wish there was an easier way to do it and still accomplish what I need to. But I've yet to find a way to do so. If you look at the JSFiddle you might understand..? I don't know, I use A LOT of comments and it's a lot of code. The main point is I have to make buttons appear inside of an if-else and inside a function / when a function is called.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add three buttons inside a DIV tag, inline. If I understand your question correctly I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function threeGamesButton() {

var x =document.getElementById("box");

var btnSet = document.createElement("div");
btnSet.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid black; width:800; height:300;" )

var firstButton = document.createElement("button");
firstButton.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid black; width:200; height:250;" );
firstButton.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction1()" );
firstButton.innerText ="Button 1";

var secondButton = document.createElement("button");
secondButton.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black; width:200; height:250;");
secondButton.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction2()" );
secondButton.innerText ="Button 2";

var thirdButton = document.createElement("button");
thirdButton.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black; width:200; height:250;")
secondButton.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction3()" );
thirdButton.innerText ="Button 1";

btnSet.appendChild(firstButton);
btnSet.appendChild(secondButton);
btnSet.appendChild(thirdButton);

x.appendChild(btnSet);
}
```

In you html page include div which has id called box. And call the function from any where..Rather than setting a attribute for (styles), you can use

```
firstButton.className = "firstButton"
```

and then add css section for that name. But If the total width of the inside buttons are larger than the div tag where you insert all these buttons, then the last button will pass to the second raw automatically...

Comment: Okay.. so I follow most of what you're saying here.. but If I want the buttons to show up when another function is called, how would I manage that. I'm not sure if that's a stupid question.. But, I'm not sure where I would put box id element. And what kind of element would it be? (I'm not too familiar with possible JS elements and the only one I really know / can think of for this is a paragraph. Would that be correct?) I'm sorry if it's a lot of questions ^^;

Comment: So I later on figured out how to do what you were saying. I realize that I just got a little confused and didn't read it correctly. But I got it in and tried it, and it didn't work. At least, not for me. The buttons didn't show up on the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out on my own, for anyone that needs it.
I have it here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniewrathh/HRZKw/5/).
But the part of the code for the buttons goes like this (ignore the odd function names) :

```
function continueIntro() 
{
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    var continueParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    continueParagraph.innerHTML = "<center>These are the buttons I finally got <br>" +
    "to center on the same line: </center>";
    document.body.appendChild(continueParagraph);

        getGoldButtons();    
}

function getGoldButtons()
{
    buttonDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    buttonDiv2.setAttribute("align","center");

    gameButton2=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    gameText2=document.createTextNode("First Option");
    gameButton2.appendChild(gameText2);
    buttonDiv2.id = "buttonDiv2";
    gameButton2.onclick = caveGetGold;
    buttonDiv2.appendChild(gameButton2);

    gameButton3=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    gameText3=document.createTextNode("Second Option");
    gameButton3.appendChild(gameText3);
    gameButton3.onclick = forestGetGold;
    buttonDiv2.appendChild(gameButton3);

    gameButton4=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    gameText4=document.createTextNode("Third Option");
    gameButton4.appendChild(gameText4);
    gameButton4.onclick = tunnelGetGold;
    buttonDiv2.appendChild(gameButton4);
    document.body.appendChild(buttonDiv2);    
}
```